# Integrating 3.x java editor in eclipse 4 RCP app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Need eclipse 4 experts help in deciding whether to go with eclipse 4 or eclipse 3 framework for my next RCP application. I have evaluated the eclipse 4 framework and it seems to be a good fit for my application, except for one requirement where I have to integrate the JDT's java editor in my application. The problem here is that the JDT's java editor itself is on 3.x. Therefore,  Is it possible to integrate this 3.x java editor in to eclipse e4 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dependencies of the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin that contains the Java editor it needs a lot of stuff from the the Eclipse 3 IDE which makes me think it would be hard to use it in anything not based on the Eclipse 3 IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I get a feeling that its better to go with 3.x framework with which I am quite comfortable as well. May be e4 still has to go a long way to mature.